# Changing between bases from $n$ to $m$

Tags: number-theory

73 to the base $x$ is equivalent to 51 to the base $y$. which of the following may be the possible values of $x$ and $y$.

a. 10, 12

b. 8, 16

c. 9, 13

d. 8, 12

how to solve it?

Comment: Which number is "73 to the base $x$"? If you translate that, you get a simple relation between $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
you know that $7x + 3 = 5y +1$, that is $7x + 2 = 5y$. Then,

> for which $x$ you have that $7x+2$ is a multiple of 5?

Answer (score 0):

Try to start this way:

$4 \equiv 1 \; mod \; 3$ is the same as $7 \equiv 1 \; mod \; 6$

so

$73 \equiv a \; mod \; x$ should be the same as $51 \equiv b \; mod \; y$

Now use the given numbers for $x,y$ and find out, in which cases $a=b$ holds